# Enabling null on many FKs to same associated table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have multiple fields setup as FK to the same table. The FK can also be NULL.

I keep getting this error:

```
ExistsIn rule for 'late_agreement_exception_outcome_recommendation_id' is invalid. 'ExceptionOutcomes' is not associated with 'App\Model\Table\ExceptionsTable'.
```

Database structure:

```
exceptions
id,
request_id,
late_agreement_exception_outcome_recommendation_id (FK, exception_outcomes->id)
late_agreement_exception_outcome_id (FK, exception_outcomes->id),
...

exception_outcomes
id,
name
...
```

Column definition (ie. late_agreement_exception_outcome_recommendation_id):

[image]

Column relationship (ie. late_agreement_exception_outcome_recommendation_id):

[image]

ExceptionTable:

FK setup to ExceptionOutcomes

```
$this->belongsTo('LateAgreementExceptionOutcomeRecommendations', [
    'class' => 'ExceptionOutcomes',
    'foreignKey' => 'late_agreement_exception_outcome_recommendation_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
]);
```

Edited rules attempting to enable entry of a null value for the field value:

```
$rules->add(
    function ($entity, $options) {
        $rule = new ExistsIn('late_agreement_exception_outcome_recommendation_id', 'ExceptionOutcomes');
        return $entity->late_agreement_exception_outcome_recommendation_id === NULL || $rule($entity, $options);
    },
    ['errorField' => 'late_agreement_exception_outcome_recommendation_id']
);
```

**Update #1**

I changed the association name like so:

```
$rules->add(
        function ($entity, $options) {
            $rule = new ExistsIn('late_agreement_exception_outcome_recommendation_id', 'LateAgreementExceptionOutcomeRecommendations');
            return $entity->late_agreement_exception_outcome_recommendation_id === NULL || $rule($entity, $options);
        },
        ['errorField' => 'late_agreement_exception_outcome_recommendation_id']
    );
```

And got the following issue simply saving the data:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sdi_ips2.late_agreement_exception_outcome_recommendations' doesn't exist
```

Previously, I could save the column when providing a value. However, trying to revert to NULL would cause an issue.

**Update #2**

```
try
{
    $this->Requests->save($request);
}
catch(Cake\Database\Exception\DatabaseException $e)
{
    debug("here!");
    exit;
}
```

**Update #3**

Here's what I see in the SQL log:

```
Generated Models
The following Table objects used Cake\ORM\Table instead of a concrete class:

LateAgreementExceptionOutcomeRecommendations
```

Comment: Your association is named `LateAgreementExceptionOutcomeRecommendations`, not `ExceptionOutcomes`, the latter is just the class name of the target table.

Comment: @ndm see update 1. I changed it per your suggestion, but now I cannot save when providing a value.

Comment: Start with checking what exactly the SQL query looks like that triggers this error.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the `save()` itself seems to be causing an issue and not quite sure how obtaining the SQL query would look like. I've tried try/catch, see update #2, and I can't seem to be able to catch it properly, something is being thrown prior by a vendor class.

Comment: Use [**debug kit**](https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/4/en/index.html)'s SQL panel or enable [**query logging**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#query-logging) for the respective datasource.

Comment: ps, you need a leading backslash in order to define a fully qualified path to the exception class, otherwise it's relative to the current namespace, and it won't catch anything.

Comment: @ndm see update 3, what I spotted in the SQL Log

Comment: Ah, right, the option for the association's class is `className`, not `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Note the `className` attribute in `belongsTo`.

```
$this->belongsTo('LateAgreementExceptionOutcomeRecommendations', [
    'className' => 'ExceptionOutcomes',
    'foreignKey' => 'late_agreement_exception_outcome_recommendation_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
]);
```